# React, Redux, Chai How do I wait for the payload of my test?

Tags: reactjs, redux, chai

I think I have to reword my question. How do trigger the action and wait for a response. I am using firebase to save my data and redux thunk.

```
import {myAction} from "../../src/js/actions/index";


describe('My Description', () => {
    it('has correct payload', () => {

        const action = myAction();

        expect(action.payload).log(); //this doesn't work
        expect(action.payload).to.equal({some:"json"}); 
        //this fails but I want to see what was returned so I can fix it
    })
})
```

//my action

```
export function myAction(data){

return dispatch => {
    //firebase
    const sectionKey =  agendaRef.push().key;
    agendaRef.child(   sectionKey  ).set(data);
    dispatch({
        type: ADD_ITEM_SAVE_SUCCESS,
        //payload: true
    })

  }
}
```

Comment: Why dont you try simple console.log(action.payload) ? If you just want to see the value.

Comment: Because I need my action to run first then get the result. action.payload is undefined

Comment: Anyway i solved it, I had to look and find mockStore library

Answer (score -2):

I had updated your code to print the payload value in the console log statement.

```
import {myAction} from "../../src/js/actions/index";
//note my action is using a dispatch method from Redux Thunk

describe('My Description', () => {
    it('has correct payload', () => {

        const action = myAction();

        console.log(action.payload); //MODIFIED line        
        expect(action.payload).to.equal({some:"json"}); 
        //this fails but I want to see what was returned so I can fix it
    })
})
```